# creating new data frames from exsting data frames with r

Tags: r, list, dataframe, filter

I have 11 data frames of Traffic counts. 
for each data frame I want to filter the relevant information (dplyr). 
but I want to do those actions in a new data frames, and give each data frame of each year a new name.I don't want to change the originals data frames.
for example **traffic_2016** new **filter_traffic_2016** and for each data frame.

```
library(foreach)
library(iterators)

foreach(x=iter(m)) %do% {
assign(x, filter(get(x), kvish %in% 1 , keta %in% 10 ,maslul %in% 1 ) ) 
}
```

the data frames look the same except from the year

```
> traffic_2016
  kvish keta maslul yom nefah status                date
1         1   10      1   1  1710     NA 2016-09-11 00:00:00
2         1   10      1   1   934     NA 2016-09-11 01:00:00
3         1   10      1   1   800     NA 2016-09-11 02:00:00
4         1   10      1   1   637     NA 2016-09-11 03:00:00
5         1   10      1   1   588     NA 2016-09-11 04:00:00
6         1   10      1   1   951     NA 2016-09-11 05:00:00
7         1   10      1   1  2312     NA 2016-09-11 06:00:00
8         1   10      1   1  3769     NA 2016-09-11 07:00:00
9         1   10      1   1  3348     NA 2016-09-11 08:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have objects of the same "kind", they should be organized to reflect it, you should put your data.frames in a list, then you can use lappy. for example:

```
traffic <- list(traffic_2014,traffic_2015,traffic_2016) # put your 11 dfs here
traffic_filtered <- traffic %>% lapply(. %>% filter(kvish %in% 1 , keta %in% 10 ,maslul %in% 1)) # get a new list with filtered data.frames
```